# What will be Terms after repeating this step(Differentiation and multiplication) F times.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, derivatives, generating-functions, symmetry

I was solving a probability problem and got stuck on the following situation, where each x_i is independent of others:

$$f=(x_1+x_2+..x_k)^N$$

I'm interested in the expression obtained after performing the operation $\phi$, $F$ times to the above.

$$\phi(f) = [D_{x_L}D_{x_{L-1}}\dots D_{x_1}(f)]\times (x_1 x_2\dots x_L)$$

(so we are looking at $\phi^F(f)$)

Work thus far:

I've used computer to find this but $n$ and $k$ are huge numbers, while $F\leq 1000$ and $L\times F \leq 100000$.

I observed that I get exactly $1+(F-1)L$ terms, in terms of different z $(x1+x2+..xk)^z$ which is quite computable, z decreasing from $n-L$ to $n-L-(F-1)L$.

What will these coefficients be ? I've failed to find further the first 2 terms though there seems some symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

The operators $x_i D_{x_i}$ for $i \ne j$ conmute, so you should start by seeing what happens with $(x_1 D_{x_1})^F f$. I bet [Leibnitz' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) helps cutting down the verbiage, and gives a clue on the terms you mention.